# Ruby on Rails. How do I use the Active Record .build method in a :belongs to relationship?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, foreign-keys

I have been unable to find any documentation on the .build method in Rails (i am currently using 2.0.2).

Through experimentation it seems you can use the build method to add a record into a `has_many` relationship before either record has been saved.

For example:

```
class Dog < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :tags
  belongs_to :person
end

class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :dogs
end

# rails c
d = Dog.new
d.tags.build(:number => "123456")
d.save # => true
```

This will save both the dog and tag with the foreign keys properly. This does not seem to work in a `belongs_to` relationship.

```
d = Dog.new
d.person.build # => nil object on nil.build
```

I have also tried

```
d = Dog.new
d.person = Person.new
d.save # => true
```

The foreign key in `Dog` is not set in this case due to the fact that at the time it is saved, the new person does not have an id because it has not been saved yet.

My questions are:

1. How does build work so that Rails is smart enough to figure out how to save the records in the right order?
2. How can I do the same thing in a `belongs_to` relationship?
3. Where can I find any documentation on this method?

Thank you

Comment: Regarding documentation, see the Rails Guides [_"Methods added by `belongs_to`"_](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#methods-added-by-belongs-to) and [_"Methods Added by `has_one`"_](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#methods-added-by-has-one). More technical documentation can be found in the API docs: [`belongs_to`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-belongs_to) and 
[`has_one`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_one).

Answer (score 157, accepted):

Where it is documented:

From the API documentation under the has_many association in "[Module ActiveRecord::Associations::ClassMethods](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html)"

> collection.build(attributes = {}, …)
>   Returns one or more new objects of the
>   collection type that have been
>   instantiated with attributes and
>   linked to this object through a
>   foreign key, but have not yet been
>   saved. Note: This only works if an
>   associated object already exists, not
>   if it‘s nil!

The answer to building in the opposite direction is a slightly altered syntax. In your example with the dogs,

```
Class Dog
   has_many :tags
   belongs_to :person
end

Class Person
  has_many :dogs
end

d = Dog.new
d.build_person(:attributes => "go", :here => "like normal")
```

or even

```
t = Tag.new
t.build_dog(:name => "Rover", :breed => "Maltese")
```

You can also use create_dog to have it saved instantly (much like the corresponding "create" method you can call on the collection)

How is rails smart enough? It's magic (or more accurately, I just don't know, would love to find out!)

Comment: @BushyMark: it uses method_missing or metaporgramming to add those methods with define_method.

Comment: @Federico where is the method missing defined?

Comment: @alock27 Same as how ActiveRecord uses method missing for your `find_by_email` and `find_by_column_name` methods. It converts the method you pass to a string and dissects it and tries to match it with your table's column names.

Comment: @edmund Thanks for your comment. To be clear, I understand how method_missing works. I was trying to locate the actual location of the file that defines this particular method missing.

Comment: @alock27 if you're asking because you want to look into how it's defined you should check out Metaprogramming Ruby. But if you really are looking for the actual location you could probably Google for the source code.

Comment: **Some observations:**
- Most online tutorials will put has_many, belongs_to in models which never worked for me.
- In reality, along with editing models,we need to MODIFY THE CONTROLLERS as well,

Answer (score 52):

```
@article = user.articles.build(:title => "MainTitle")
@article.save
```

Comment: >> d.tags.build(:number => "123456")
>> d.save # => true

Not the same?