# Building embedded mongoid documents in form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

I might be missing something silly but I can't get multiple embedded photo files into a form

Models

```
class Product
   include Mongoid::Document

   embeds_many :photos, cascade_callbacks: true
end

class Photo
   include Mongoid::Document

   embedded_in product, :inverse_of => :photos
   field :image_filename
   mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader
end
```

Controller - products_controller.rb

```
def new
   @product = Product.new
   3.times { @product.photos.build }
end
```

Form

Then I do the form with

```
fields_for @product.photos do |photo|
   <%= photo.file_field :image %>
end
```

The problem is only 1 photo is showing up but I am building 3 in the controller. The count for @product.photos.count is 0 even after i build 3 in memory. Am I missing something?

Comment: Similar to this, I think you need the product to "build" first. Basically, @product doesn't exist yet (you didn't "save" it) so any collection-based associations will also return "nil" http://stackoverflow.com/questions/783584/ruby-on-rails-how-do-i-use-the-active-record-build-method-in-a-belongs-to-rel

Comment: @product is already created in memory through the Product.new call. This is very common in ActiveRecord but for some reason it's not working within Mongoid and embedded documents

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
fields_for @product.photos do |photo|
   <%= photo.file_field :image %>
end
```

should be

```
fields_for :photos do |photo|
   <%= photo.file_field :image %>
end
```