# what does this rails syntax mean?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Ok so I built this application a while which was a rails 2.3.5 application and i used this syntax

```
@user = User.new
@user.build_company
```

and I totally forgot what this meant and how to convert to rails 3 syntax

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :company

class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :user
```

I vaguely remember that rails will use build_ and do something but i cant remember and I cant seem to find the documentation anywhere

Answer (score 2):

`.build_` will make a new object of the associated type (a Company) that is linked to the object it's called on (a User), but which is not yet saved. 
AFAIK this hasn't changed in Rails 3.

See this question:
[Ruby on Rails. How do I use the Active Record .build method in a :belongs to relationship?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/783584/ruby-on-rails-how-do-i-use-the-active-record-build-method-in-a-belongs-to-rel)

And the docs it points to:
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html

Answer (score 2):

That is correct syntax for Rails 3.

has_one relationship:

```
@parent.build_child
```

has_many relationship:

```
@parent.children.build
```