# Rails build method modifies object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Let's say I have this simple method in my helper that helps me to retrieve a client:

```
def current_client 
  @current_client ||= Client.where(:name => 'my_client_name').first
end
```

Now calling `current_client` returns this:

```
#<Client _id: 5062f7b851dbb2394a00000a, _type: nil, name: "my_client_name">
```

Perfect. The client has a few associated users, let's look at the last one:

```
> current_client.user.last
#<User _id: 5062f7f251dbb2394a00000e, _type: nil, name: "user_name">
```

Later in a `new` method I call this:

```
@new_user = current_client.user.build
```

And now, to my surprise, calling `current_client.user.last` returns

```
#<User _id: 50635e8751dbb2127c000001, _type: nil, name: nil>
```

but users count doesn't change. In other words - it doesn't add the new user but one user is missing... Why is this? How can I repair it?

Comment: Does users.count stay the same? Or is it users.length that stays the same?

Comment: @new_user.save

see: [Build Method][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/783584/ruby-on-rails-how-do-i-use-the-active-record-build-method-in-a-belongs-to-rel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`current_client.users.count` makes a round trip to the database to figure out how many user records are associated. Since the new user hasn't been saved yet (it's only been built) the database doesn't know about it.

`current_client.users.length` will give you the count using Ruby.

```
current_client.users.count # => 2
current_client.users.length # => 2
current_client.users.build
current_client.users.count # => 2
current_client.users.length # => 3
```

Comment: OK, thanks for explanation.
To avoid this situation I changed my new method to something like: 
`current_client_dup = current_client.dup
@user = current_client_dup.user.build`