# unknown attribute :avatar when uploading with image i am getting this error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, paperclip

I am getting error at in registrationscontroller at 15 and 99
I have done following in my app

```
def user_params
#assumption: user params are coming in params[:user]
params.require(:user).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :mobile, :uid, :provider, :avatar )
end
in user.rb

has_attached_file :avatar, :styles => { :medium => "300x300>", :thumb => "100x100>" }, :default_url => "/images/:style/missing.png"
validates_attachment_content_type :avatar, :content_type => /\Aimage\/.*\Z/

in migration

class AddAvatarToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change

add_attachment :users, :avatar

  end
end

ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError in MyDevise::RegistrationsController#create

app/controllers/my_devise/registrations_controller.rb:99:in `build_resource'
app/controllers/my_devise/registrations_controller.rb:15:in `create'
```

Extracted source (around line #99):

```
def create
15.   self.resource = build_resource(sign_up_params)
if resource.save
  # yield resource if block_given?
  if resource.active_for_authentication?
    set_flash_message :notice, :signed_up if is_flashing_format?
    sign_up(resource_name, resource)
    respond_with resource, :location => after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
  else
    set_flash_message :notice, :"signed_up_but_#{resource.inactive_message}" if is_flashing_format?
    expire_data_after_sign_in!
    respond_with resource, :location => after_inactive_sign_up_path_for(resource)
  end
else
  clean_up_passwords resource
  respond_with resource
end
end

# temporary session data to the newly created user.
def build_resource(hash=nil)
99   self.resource = resource_class.new_with_session(hash || {}, session)
end

# Signs in a user on sign up. You can overwrite this method in your own
```

Comment: migration successful?

Answer (score 0):

[**Build**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/783584/ruby-on-rails-how-do-i-use-the-active-record-build-method-in-a-belongs-to-rel)

I think your problem is to do with `Devise` `building` your objects:

```
def build_resource(hash=nil)
    self.resource = resource_class.new_with_session(hash || {}, session)
end
```

You're confusing Devise's operations (it's best to leave Devise alone & add functionality on top of it)

---

**Extra Fields**

Here's what I'd do:

1. Set up Devise to handle extra attributes
2. Add extra attributes *after* registration

---

[**Params**](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#strong-parameters)

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_filter :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

  protected

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) << :avatar
  end
end
```

---

**Fields**

You can use these resources to add extra attributes to your model when registering new users:

- [RailsCast - Customizing Devise](http://railscasts.com/episodes/210-customizing-devise?view=comments)
- [Blog - Adding Custom Fields To Devise](http://blog.12spokes.com/web-design-development/adding-custom-fields-to-your-devise-user-model-in-rails-4/)

From the looks of it, changing the params selector, you should be able to upload the `avatar` image through the registration form

Comment: Nice you might want to consider accepting my answer ;)