# before_create doesn't work in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In a rails project, I have 3 controllers and models, user, responsibility and profile. I have below code:

`user.rb`

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  has_one :responsibility
  has_one :profile

  before_create :build_responsibility
  before_create :build_profile

end
```

`responsibility.rb`

```
class Responsibility < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :user

end
```

`profile.rb`

```
class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :user

  validates :user_id, uniqueness: true

  validates_numericality_of :nic_code, :allow_blank => true
  validates_numericality_of :phone_number

  validates_length_of :phone_number, :minimum => 11, :maximum => 11
  validates_length_of :nic_code, :minimum => 10, :maximum => 10, :allow_blank => true

  has_attached_file :photo, :styles => { :medium => "300x300>", :thumb => "35x35>" }, :default_url => "profile-missing.jpg"
  validates_attachment_content_type :photo, :content_type => [ 'image/gif', 'image/png', 'image/x-png', 'image/jpeg', 'image/pjpeg', 'image/jpg' ]

end
```

Now, when I created a new user, `before_create` works for `responsibility` and creates it, but for `profile` it's not working and doesn't create a new profile. Is there a difference between `profile` and `responsibility`? Why `before_create` works for `responsibility`, but doesn't work for `profile`?

Comment: `build_responsibility` - t's some build-in activerecord method? Or why you didn't show it?

Comment: Post your `before_create` code,so that it is easy to find a solution.

Comment: looks like it's really build in [method](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-belongs_to)

Comment: I just use `before_create` and don't have any code for `before_create`.

Comment: is `before_create` a rails built-in helper? I could't find it in `api`

Comment: You should be using some method with `before_create` right? Post that method.

Comment: @WaliAli http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html

Comment: `before_create` allows you to build objects on the fly with `build_[object]` - it just creates a blank version of the associative model, with your `foreign_key` populated

Comment: @RichPeck thanks. i'm reading the link now

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will almost certainly be a [validation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html) issue:

```
#app/models/profile.rb
validates_length_of :phone_number, :minimum => 11, :maximum => 11
validates_length_of :nic_code, :minimum => 10, :maximum => 10, :allow_blank => true
```

When you [`build`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/783584/ruby-on-rails-how-do-i-use-the-active-record-build-method-in-a-belongs-to-rel) an ActiveRecord object, the models will not be populated with data. This means your validations are going to have no data to validate, which I believe will throw the error

You need to test by removing the `length` & `presence` validations in your `Profile` model:

```
#app/models/profile.rb
class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user

  # -> test without validations FOR NOW
end
```

Comment: I set `:allow_blank => true` to all validation field and it's work, Thanks.

Comment: Thanks this makes sense. Also, I found this guide to be useful: https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html