# How to add dynamic value for a column in ruby on rails model with Active Record Callbacks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-activerecord, ruby-on-rails-6, rails-models

I have a model `Document` in my rails application. It has columns `name`, and `key`.

In my controller for `create` action, I get document name from the frontend and dynamically set one value for `key` with `securerandom`.

The implementation I have for this case is:

## Document model

```
class Document < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :user
    validates :key, presence: true, uniqueness: true
end
```

## Documents Controller

```
class DocumentsController < ApplicationController
    def create
        current_user.documents.create(create_document_params)
        redirect_to '/'
    end

    private
    def create_document_params
        params.require(:document).permit(:name).merge(key: "#{SecureRandom.hex(6)}#{Time.now.to_i}")
    end
end
```

The problem with this approach is that the dynamic key logic is in the controller which I think should be the part of the Document model.

For that, I tried using `Active Record Callbacks` inside the `Document` model with `before_create`.
I moved the securerandom key logic to the Document model like this:

```
class Document < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :user
    validates :key, uniqueness: true


    before_create do
        self.key = "#{SecureRandom.hex(6)}#{Time.now.to_i}"
    end
end
```

But now my problem is, whenever I call `create` or `new` `key` value is always the same. But it should be randomly generated before every `create` call.

In the rails console

```
u = User.find_by(user_name: "random")
u.documents.new(name: 'Yolo 1') // key: "89c9013c191a1589398865"
u.documents.new(name: 'Yolo 2') // key: "89c9013c191a1589398865"
```

What I am doing wrong?

Edit: Added Gemfile :

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
git_source(:github) { |repo| "https://github.com/#{repo}.git" }

ruby '2.6.3'

gem 'rails', '~> 6.0.3'
gem 'sqlite3', '~> 1.4'
gem 'puma', '~> 4.1'
gem 'sass-rails', '>= 6'
gem 'webpacker', '~> 4.0'
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.7'
gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'
gem 'bootsnap', '>= 1.4.2', require: false

group :development, :test do
gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
end

group :development do
gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
gem 'listen', '~> 3.2'
gem 'spring'
gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
end

group :test do
gem 'capybara', '>= 2.15'
gem 'selenium-webdriver'
gem 'webdrivers'
end

gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]

gem "rspec-rails", "~> 4.0"
```

DB Migration:

```
class CreateDocuments < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
    def change
        create_table :documents do |t|
            t.string :name,
            t.string :key, index: {unique: true}, null: false
            t.references :user
            t.timestamps
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: The same value? Interesting... What the value yours documents records have? You are testing using controller create or using `rails console`?

Comment: Other thing: You need remove `#merge` from your controller.

Comment: Yes I have removed `merge` when trying `Active Record Callbacks` and I am trying with `rails console`

Comment: for every `doc = current_user.documents.create(name: 'some name')`  `doc.key` is same.

Answer (score 0):

I replicate your scenario on my application and a can reproduce your error.
This behaviour is about the validates method. I remove that and its works.

For stay the validates, i [found this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23708631/2638434)

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

class Document < ApplicationRecord
  before_create :assing_key

  belongs_to :user

  validates :key, presence: true, uniqueness: true, allow_blank: true

  private

  def assing_key
    self.key = "#{SecureRandom.hex(6)}#{Time.now.to_i}"
  end
end
```

I add `allow_blank: true`.

You can test removing only `presence` instead of add `allow_blank` also. Enjoy.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your answer.  I tried your solution, but it is not working, the problem still persists. Is it because of my db migration? `t.string :key, index: {unique: true}, null: false` ?

Comment: your migration does not affect model scope. It is a rule on database.
Otherwise, try remove your `validates` method and come back with result.

Comment: You can check error message on model too. `doc = Document.create(name: "foo")`. After `doc.errors` to see especifc message.

Comment: The error I am getting is with key: `:key=>[{:error=>:taken, :value=>"89c9013c191a1589398865"}]`, This is  because it is not creating new keys.

Comment: It is very strange... Do as my example class: Move `before_create` first line inside class, create a private method do assing your key e pass as symbol to `before_create` and remove `validates` method. Make class more clear for avoid suspicious parts.

Comment: I copied exactly the same code in my file, saved it, and still no luck.

Comment: If you run `"#{SecureRandom.hex(6)}#{Time.now.to_i}"` on rails console, brings differents results any time?

Comment: yes `"#{SecureRandom.hex(6)}#{Time.now.to_i}"` returns new value every time in console

Comment: Add your `Gemfile` content on your question.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you was able to create a doc because you had the validation of `presence: true` on the `key`. You would get error `{:key=>["can't be blank"]}` when creating the doc with `doc = current_user.documents.create(name: 'some name')`because the validation is being executed before the call back `before_create`. All you need to do is to remove `presence: true` since you always set it before creating a new record.

Comment: That is a different case, Even without the validation when I try `current_user.documents.create(name: 'some name')` in rails console, I am getting the same key every time, that is the major concern.