# Build method not saving record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

agent.rb

```
has_many :organisations
```

Organisation.rb

```
belongs_to :agent
```

organisations_agent.rb

```
validates :organisation_id, uniqueness: { scope: [:agent_id] }
```

organisations_controller.rb

```
def create
    @organisation = current_agent.organisations.build(organisation_params)
    @organisation.save
end
private

def organisation_params
  params.require(:organisation).permit(:name, :organisation_size, :area, :management)
end
```

I have the following associations as above. The issue I am facing here is that in the create action when I try to create an organisation I am getting an error that agent_id is blank because of which build doesn't save the record. Please help me find where I am going wrong.

I added binding.pry_remote right before the @organisation.save and I checked that in @organisation the agent_id is nil. So I checked if there is actually a current_agent in the create agent and yes that works fine. I am getting current_agent in the create action. I don't know where I am going wrong but agent_id is nil in @oganisation in create action.

params content

```
 id: nil,
 name: "ABC Org",
 organisation_size: "35",
 area: "USA"
 agent_id: nil,
 management: "DEMO"
```

Comment: how `organisation_params` method looks like? are you permitting the values you need?

Comment: @mr_sudaca i have added the params. Please check now. Yes I am permitting the values.

Comment: have you checked the params passed to the controller? you should be able to see that in the log output, could be something easy to fix, like a typo

Comment: @mr_sudaca please check the update in the question

Comment: could you print `params` content as well?

Comment: @mr_sudaca params added.  Please check in question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214931/discussion-between-mr-sudaca-and-user12763413).

Comment: you are permitting `agent_id` so it is likely that `agent_id` is being passed to the action as `nil`. Thus `organisation_params` is overriding the build parameter for `agent_id`

Comment: @engineersmnky yes you are right. I removed it from the permitted params and tried it. still the agent_id is nil

Comment: Can you post the code for `current_agent`?

Comment: @engineersmnky
i am using devise. so getting current agent from there. 
I am getting the current_agent in the create action
<Agent id: 14, name: "XYZ", email: "xyz@yahoo.com", created_at: "2020-05-29 18:19:20", updated_at: "2020-05-29 18:23:39>

Comment: What if you try `save!`, then you get a validation error if there is any

Comment: Please check if [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/783584/ruby-on-rails-how-do-i-use-the-active-record-build-method-in-a-belongs-to-rel) helps you